# Do I really need WSUS and if I disable WSUS will the workstation automatically pickup windows updates?

Tags: windows, wsus, windows-sbs-2011

When I setup SBS 2011 several years ago, it automatically setup WSUS.  We have 6 workstations and the server in the office.  WSUS is taking up too much server space and I find it frustrating to maintain.  I have spent days trying to clean up old updates with WSUS consoles keep on crashing.

Do I really need WSUS?  Any easy instruction to disable WSUS?  Will the 6 workstations automatically go out to get Windows updates after I disable WSUS?

Answer (score 6):

> Do I really need WSUS?

No.  You can configure computers to pull updates directly from Microsoft, in which case you will not need WSUS.

> Any easy instruction to disable WSUS?

1. Remove the WSUS Server role (in Server Manager)
2. Check `C:\WSUS\` for leftover content/packages,  and delete if needed.  Leave the database folders intact to avoid SQL issues.
3. This may leave metadata/database files behind, but those are usually relatively small.

> Will the 6 workstations automatically go out to get Windows updates after I disable WSUS?

Generally, no.  Clients (including the Windows Update client on the server itself) are configured to use a given WSUS server by Group Policy Object (GPO).  The GPO(s) will need to be modified.

1. Open GPMC (Group Policy Management Console)
2. Check/edit the appropriate GPO(s)
3. Computer Policies -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Windows Update
4. Change the "Set the intranet ..." items (there are two) to Unconfigured
5. If desired, adjust other items, such as update install schedule/frequency

Be sure to follow-up and check workstations, and make sure they are properly getting updates.  Continue checking periodically.  Falling behind on updates often leads to security compromise (virus, worm, ransomware, etc.).

References:

- https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sbs/2009/09/23/how-to-move-wsus-content-and-database-files-to-a-different-volume/
- https://slice2.com/2016/11/11/howto-delete-the-wsus-wid-on-windows-2012r2/